# Ambient Occlusion Help

Tags: texturing

I am trying to bake and ambient occlusion texture to my object but a few of the faces are turning up black. I know the are facing the right direction as I have recalculated the normals and flipped them manually in the shading/UV tab multiple times. IN the picture is hows a handle that I have built quickly  that has the problem. It is not a complex object at all just a spawned cylinder scaled down and extruded a could times and moved to look like a handle. I don't know why just a few of the faces are black doesn't make any sense to me. A lot of the cylinders I have used have the problem. Also the actual .png that has the textures laid out on it does not show the black just the red like it is supposed to be.[image]

Comment: Just adding to my post the faces that turn up black do not have a texture at all in the uv image editor so idk why when i bake the model as a whole it misses these faces

Comment: If you add a file with blendexchange I will take a look at it when I get home. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4076" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4076/) @SilverRain Thank You!!!